# select2.min.js:21 Uncaught query function not defined for Select2 s2id_City_Id

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, ajax

I am updating record the record it's updating the record. but i need to refresh the page to see the results... here is my code

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#interviewcenter-edit-details .select2me').select2({
        placeholder: "Select an option",
        allowClear: true
    });
});
```

i searched but that are not working for me.

Comment: any error in console ? and what is the id you are using , a server control?

Comment: this is the error in the console.............select2.min.js:21 Uncaught query function not defined for Select2 s2id_City_Id